# symfony2 & doctrine orderBy/DQL error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I have 2 entities defined:

- State entity
- City entity

I am trying to select the state entity and automatically join the city entity and order the results by state's name. However, I get this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 74: Error: Expected Literal, got 'BY'
```

My code to create the query is:

```
$statesQuery = $this->getEm()->createQueryBuilder();
$statesQuery->select("st");
$statesQuery->from("CoreBundle:State", "st");
$statesQuery->leftJoin("CoreBundle:City", "ct");
$statesQuery->addSelect("ct");
$statesQuery->orderBy("st.name", "ASC");

$statesQuery = $statesQuery->getQuery();

$states = $statesQuery->getResult();
```

If I remove the order By method I get the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got end of string.
```

The DQL generated queries ( with order By and w/o orderBy):

```
SELECT st, ct FROM CoreBundle:State st LEFT JOIN CoreBundle:City ct ORDER BY s.name ASC

SELECT st, ct FROM CoreBundle:State st LEFT JOIN CoreBundle:City ct
```

**The state entity:**

```
Ec\CoreBundle\Entity\State:
    type: entity
    table: states
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            unsigned: false
            comment: ''
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 255
        friendly_url:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 255
    oneToMany:
        cities:
            targetEntity: City
            mappedBy: state
    oneToOne:
        country:
            targetEntity: Country
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**And the city entity:**

```
Ec\CoreBundle\Entity\City:
    type: entity
    table: cities
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            unsigned: false
            comment: ''
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 255
        friendly_url:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 255
    manyToOne:
        state:
            targetEntity: State
            inversedBy: cities
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: You're ordering by `s.name` and you don't define `s` in your query.

Comment: I did a lot of trial and error before posting this question here and the "s.name" probably slipped. I've corrected my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to retrieve a collection of states (and the associated cities), this is enough:

```
// src/AcmeBundle/Controller/MyController.php
// ...

$statesQuery = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$statesQuery->select("st")
            ->from("CoreBundle:State", "st")
            ->orderBy("st.name", "ASC");

$states = $statesQuery->getQuery()
                      ->getResult();
```

So the cities will be lazy loaded. For more info about lazy/eager loading check the [doctrine2 doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone)

**EDIT:**
Ok, if you need this only in one place, simply do:

```
$statesQuery = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$statesQuery->select("st, ct")
            ->from("CoreBundle:State", "st")
            ->leftJoin("st.cities", "ct")
            ->orderBy("st.name", "ASC");

$states = $statesQuery->getQuery()
                      ->getResult();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm displaying a list of all states and their cities, resulting in 54 queries if I load the cities in lazy mode. This is the only page in the app where I need the cities to be loaded eagerly so I can't set the fetch type to eager in my entity definition. The country Entity is there just to support easy implementation in the future for extra countries, at this point I have only one country added to my database. I can confirm though that if I don't load eagerly the cities, the order by statement works.

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer, now you can see how to get the data eagerly.

Comment: @raullarion if the answer solve your problem, please check as accepted

Comment: so ->select("st", "ct") was actually the problem solver. I didn't see that :-) Thank you!